# Scale of Model in Blender is not same in .stl

Tags: modeling, export

I have set the scale to 0.0254, which makes Blender display correct dimensions in inches. But when I export to .stl, the diameter of my circle in the model is 2.75mm instead of 2.75 inches. Also, I am trying to get these models 3D printed, using printing services, and each time I do so, the file scale is wrong and I have gotten several incorrect parts as a result. How do I guarantee that Blender is exporting the dimensions I need them to be?

Comment: have you tried to set the scale in meters/millimeters in Blender (it is possible that the stl exporter is bad converting the scale) ?

Comment: I thought I had tried that, but when I went to change the units, changing them to meters seemed to do the trick. I wish it wasn't so confusing.